# python email decode_header raise HeaderParseError

Tags: python

I got a HeaderParseError as below.What's wrong with it?

```
>>> from email import Header
>>> s= "=?UTF-8?B?6KGM6KGM5ZyI5Li65oKo5o6o6I2Q5Lul5LiL6IGM5L2N77yM?==?UTF-8?B?56Wd5oKo5om+5Yiw5aW95bel5L2c77yB44CQ6KGM6KGM5ZyI44CR?="
>>> src = Header.decode_header(s)
```

This is the error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/email/header.py", line 108, in decode_header
    raise HeaderParseError
email.errors.HeaderParseError
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are trying to parse two headers at once:

```
"=?UTF-8?B?6KGM6KGM5ZyI5Li65oKo5o6o6I2Q5Lul5LiL6IGM5L2N77yM?="
```

and

```
"=?UTF-8?B?56Wd5oKo5om+5Yiw5aW95bel5L2c77yB44CQ6KGM6KGM5ZyI44CR?="
```

removing one of them will do the job. If you want to parse all of them - you have to split them first